# Different permission for different group

Tags: linux, permissions, users, group

I create a folder using `sudo mkdir main` perssion of this folder is `drwxrwxr--` it belongs to a group `execute` now i have also one more group `read`. I created 2 users first `user1` and second is `user2` now i want to add `user2` in `read` group that can only read file and want to add `user1` to `execute` group that can read, write and execute, how can i do that, and i already created 2 users and group but tell me how can i give specific permission to a specific group in order to achieve my task.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd say you'll have to deal with [ACL's](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-manage-acls-on-linux).

Comment: Thanks for replying, can't i achive this by simply giving all permission to `execute` group and read permission `read` group or something like that ?

Comment: I suppose you could set 774 permissions which would mean the directory owner and group would have full access and "other" would only have read permissions. But that would not distinguish between `execute` and `read` groups but between `execute` and all other groups. If that's what you need, this would probably be the way to go.

Comment: Hey thanks @eblock you were right ACL works.